# On Android 4.4.2, WebView loads slowly

Tags: android, webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I have a list and when I click on one item of the list, one HTML page is called like that:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", content, "text/html", "utf-8", "about:blank");
```

Inside this webview, there is HTML5 video (I'm using this library https://github.com/cprcrack/VideoEnabledWebView). When I enter in full screen mode with the video, then return to the list and click on another item to load an HTML page, this page takes too long to load (like minutes).
This only happens on some 4.4.2 devices, on the emulator it loads quickly.

My hardwareAccelerated is enabled.

I found out that if I rotate the screen, the second page loads quickly. But I tried to reload the page ou setting to clear the view, but it didn't work.

Does anyone has any idea why this happens?

I'm also  getting this error:

**[ERROR:in_process_view_renderer.cc(193)] Failed to request GL process. Deadlock likely: 0**

Answer (score 0):

If your working on web view i would suggest to look on [crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org) and [chromium](http://www.chromium.org/developers). Its best way to bring in hardware acceleration into the project.

Comment: I did that. But I still can't find the solution.